# A formula for the derivative of $f(x) = y(x)/x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have problem with proving something in first principle differentiation.

How to prove that:

$$f(x)'  =\frac{x y(x)'-y(x)}{  x^2}$$

where  $f(x) = y(x)/x$ ?

The problem is where the $y(x)'$ came from?! If I knew where it came from, I would prove that easily.

Comment: I think $y(x)$ is just being defined as a function satisfying $f(x)=y(x)/x$ i.e. one defined by $xf(x)=y(x)$. Just differentiate the second equation to receive the first.

Comment: It's just the chain rule and quotient rule.

Comment: $$\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)':= \frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

We are going to get the derivative of $f(x)=\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$ applying the definition of derivative. It is:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}f'(x) & = & \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\ & = &  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{u(x+h)}{v(x+h)}-\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}}{h} \\ & = &  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(x+h)v(x)-u(x)v(x+h)}{hv(x)v(x+h)} \\ & = &  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(x+h)v(x)-u(x)v(x)+u(x)v(x)-u(x)v(x+h)}{hv(x)v(x+h)} \\ & = &  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(x+h)v(x)-u(x)v(x)}{hv(x)v(x+h)}-  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(x)v(x+h)-u(x)v(x)}{hv(x)v(x+h)} \\ & = &  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{hv(x+h)}-  u(x)\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{v(x+h)-v(x)}{hv(x)v(x+h)}   \\ & = &  \frac{u'(x)}{v(x)}-\frac{u(x)v'(x)}{v^2(x).}\end{array}$$

Now, if $v(x)=x,$ we have

$$\left(\frac{u(x)}{x}\right)'=u'(x)-\frac{u(x)}{x^2}.$$